# Удалить строки меньше 8 СИМВОЛОВ (не байт, а символов!), utf-8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, char, length

```
mysql> show full columns from bpsw;
+--------+--------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field  | Type         | Collation | Null | Key | Default | Extra | Privileges                      | Comment |
+--------+--------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| badpsw | varchar(128) | utf8_bin  | NO   |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
+--------+--------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Default NULL и NOT NULL уже обсуждалось.

---

Нужно удалить все строки меньше 8 символов. Я уже это сделал, но неправ... не эффективно, не по научному. Догадываюсь что, наверное, в условии на удаление нужно указать кодировку или использовать не `length`. Как правивльно это сделать?

```
mysql> delete from bpsw where length(badpsw)<8;
Query OK, 574139 rows affected (12.27 sec)
```

---

```
mysql> delete from bpsw where badpsw like "_";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.82 sec)

mysql> delete from bpsw where badpsw like "__";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.81 sec)

mysql> delete from bpsw where badpsw like "___";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.83 sec)

mysql> delete from bpsw where badpsw like "____";
Query OK, 2862 rows affected (0.97 sec)

mysql> delete from bpsw where badpsw like "_____";
Query OK, 6624 rows affected (0.85 sec)

mysql> delete from bpsw where badpsw like "______";
Query OK, 10164 rows affected (0.88 sec)

mysql> delete from bpsw where badpsw like "_______";
Query OK, 12903 rows affected (0.92 sec)
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length

Comment: Я не вполне уверен в том что делаю (зачем создавать такую таблицу). В ней будут хранится часто используемые пароли БОЛЬШЕ 7 символов. При смене пароля думаю проверять пароль по этой табличке НО все хеши лежат в бкрипте. Смысл в использовании тут, наверное, в усложнении подюора пароля хакпользователем И УСЛОЖНЕНИЕ ЖИЗНИ обычным пользователям(?) А я еще подумываю о введении параметра "Блокировать учетн запись после 3 неудачн попыток аутентификаци".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete from bpsw where CHAR_LENGTH (badpsw)<8
```

Comment: Пробел-то зачем?

Comment: @akina какой пробел?

Comment: Между именем функции и открывающей скобкой...

Comment: @Akina, "лишний" пробел не вызывает ошибки. Почему так - я незн. Нужно детально в оффдоки смотреть.

Comment: есть некий параметр, (непомню название), который влияет на пробел перед скобкой.  но я его не трогал. Если написать `select max (bpswid) from bpsw;` это приведет к ошибке. А в случае с `CHAR_LENGTH (badpsw)` ошибки нет.